# Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.KYCStatusl'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to the sql server. I have imported two tables in database. and ran a simple query to view the tables. the query is: select * from [dbo].[KYCStatus]

but it is giving me a error message instead of the resul. the error message is: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.KYCStatusl'

I have checked the table, refreshed it re refreshed it, refreshed local cache but with out any effect. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanking in advance,
Sadat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SQL Server Management Studio?  IF so, highlight the select query and then execute the query.  This should execute the highlighted code.  It sounds like you are executing something other than your select query.

Comment: Hello :) thanks for your quick reply. I have highlighted the select query but now it says: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'select'. I do not know what is wrong wiht it. I have seen result with this query. But next I see errors. :(

Comment: Try copying the select query into a new query window and then run it there.

Comment: Hi. Just figured it out. I have not USEd my original DB where the tables are rather another DB. Once I corrected that out, the code started to execute safely :) but thanks for your help :)